# MVC 4 JSON object does map to ViewModel

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

There are many postings to this problem, but I still can't get it to work.  I have a submission form, that contains workorder and technician information, a long with a list of his/her submissions for the workorder. (Similar to order and order detail form).

Below is my ViewModel:

```
public class SubmissionVM
{
  public SubmissionVM()
  {
    this.WorkorderLogs = new List<WorkorderLog>();
    this.ShiftLogs = new List<ShiftLog>();
  }

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ProductionTypeId { get; set; }
  public int WorkorderId { get; set; }
  public int ActivityId { get; set; }
  public int WorkstationId { get; set; }
  public int PlatformId { get; set; }
  public int PartId { get; set; }
  public int TechnicianId { get; set; }
  public int ShiftId { get; set; }
  public System.DateTime ShiftDate { get; set; }
  public decimal ShiftDuration { get; set; }

  public List<WorkorderLog> WorkorderLogs { get; set; }
  public List<ShiftLog> ShiftLogs { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Below is my AJAX call(WOItems and ShiftItems are the detail items):

```
$('#btncreate').click(function () {
  var isAllValid = true;
  var url = $(this).data('link');

  // Do some checking

  if (isAllValid) {
    var data = {
      WorkorderId: parseInt($('#WorkorderId').val().trim()),
      ProductionTypeId: parseInt($('#ProductionTypeId').val().trim()),
      ActivityId: parseInt($('#ActivityId').val().trim()),
      WorkstationId: parseInt($('#WorkstationId').val().trim()),
      PlatformId: parseInt($('#PlatformId').val().trim()),
      PartId: parseInt($('#PartId').val().trim()),
      TechnicianId: parseInt($('#TechnicianId').val().trim()),
      ShiftId: parseInt($('#ShiftId').val().trim()),
      ShiftDate: parseInt($('#ShiftDate').val().trim()),
      ShiftDuration: parseFloat($('#ShiftDuration').val().trim()),
      WorkorderLogs: WOItems,
      ShiftLogs: ShiftItems
}

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                contentType: 'applicaton/json',
                success: function (d) {
                    alert('Success');
                    $('#btncreate').val('Create');
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error');
                    $('#btncreate').val('Create');
                }
            });
        } // END if(isAllValid)
    }); // END $('#btncreate').click()
```

Screenshot from Chrome Developer Tools:

[image: JSON Object to be sent to Controller]

Screenshot from the server side:
[image: Values not mapped to ViewModel]

I have made the names exactly the same, but it can't map.  Am I missing something?

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveSubmission(SubmissionVM submissionvm)
{
  bool status = false;

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    Submission submission = new Submission();

    foreach (var woLog in submissionvm.WorkorderLogs)
    {
      woLog.SubmissionDate = DateTime.Now;
      submission.WorkorderLogs.Add(woLog);
    }

    foreach (var shiftLog in submissionvm.ShiftLogs)
    {
      shiftLog.SubmissionDate = DateTime.Now;
      submission.ShiftLogs.Add(shiftLog);
    }

    db.Submissions.Add(submission);
    db.SaveChanges();

    status = true;
  } // END ModelState.IsValid()
  else
  {
    status = false;
  }

  return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
} // END SaveSubmission()
```

Comment: You have specified the `contentType: 'json'` so you need to stringify the data - `data: JSON.stringify(data),` but its unnecessary to build your data manually like that. If the view is correct, then remove `contentType` and just use `data: $('form').serialize()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into it a little close and you've misspelled the value in contentType. You have `'applicaton/json'` notice you are mission the 'i' in 'application'.

I would recommend you use the complete name:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Comment: I modified the code as you mentioned, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post what your action method is expecting?

Comment: I have included the controller code above.  I put a break point at the beginning of the if statement.  You can see from the screenshot that the property values for submissionvm are either 0 or null.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I spent the whole day trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

In your Ajax request please add the following:

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in `contentType`, use

`contentType: 'application/json'`

also make your data `json` string like

`data: JSON.stringify(data)`